# How to count only certain values in one column ​and others dont touch?

Tags: r

I have a df like this

```
head(df)
# Date         Mongolia 
# 2020-04-14   100000 
# 2020-04-15   6000 
# 2020-04-21   300000 
# 2020-04-21   400 
# 2020-04-23   20 
# 2020-04-23   120
```

I want to divide all four-digit and bigger numbers by 1000

newdf will be like:

```
head(newdf) 
# Date         Mongolia 
# 2020-04-14   100 
# 2020-04-15   6 
# 2020-04-21   300
# 2020-04-21   400 
# 2020-04-23   20 
# 2020-04-23   120
```

Appreciate it.

Comment: Why is 6000 divided by 1000? It's four-digit.

Comment: Good point. Sorry, I want to divide all four-digit and bigger numbers by 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` or `case_when`

```
df$Mongolia <- ifelse(nchar(df$Mongolia) >=5, df$Mongolia/5, df$Mongolia)
```

or just indexing

```
i1 <- nchar(df$Mongolia) >=5
```

Or use `%/%`

```
i1 <- (df$Mongolia %/% 1e4) > 0
df$Mongolia[i1] <-  df$Mongolia[i1]/1000
```